# Angular tsconfig not able to access the module specified in the paths

Tags: angular, tsconfig

I am using angular version 11. So I have created constants folder under the app to use common variables in entire application. For accessing that, I should import like below
"../../constants/user.constants"

For avoiding this, I have updated values in tsconfig.json like below

```
"baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@constants/*": ["src/app/constants/*"]
},
```

This is not working. I am getting the below error

```
import { USER_TYPE_COMPANY_USER } from '@constants/user.constants';

"baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
          "@constants/*": ["app/constants/*"]
    },
```

I was trying this also and not working

Could anyone help to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create common variables in entire application then you can use these :

1.you can create shared services : import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

```
@Injectable()  
export class DataService {  
  
  private data = {};  
  
 setOption(option, value) {      
    this.data[option] = value;  
  }  
  
  getOption() {  
    return this.data;  
  }  
}
```

and use it like this

```
   constructor(_dataService: DataService) { 
      }
```

for more on shared service you can follow:https://developerslogblog.wordpress.com/2019/04/23/how-to-use-angular-services-to-share-data-between-components/

2. you can create lets say `constants.ts` file and export variable from there and import wherever needed